# Countably dimensional Hilbert Spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces

I have seen a simple proof that no Banach space over $\mathbb{R}$ can be of countably infinite dimension.  However since the space of all square integrable functions on the unit interval forms a Hilbert space, and all Hilbert Spaces are Banach, this space must not be of countable dimension.  However we know that each point has a unique decomposition as a sum complex exponentials $e^{2n\pi}$ were $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.  Thus these complex exponentials form a basis.  But since there is a countable number of such exponentials there must be a contradiction.  Where is that contradiction?

Comment: Basis $\ne$ Schauder basis. You’re talking about a countable Schauder basis for the space; it’s not a basis, since you allow infinite sums.

Comment: Better to say "Hamel basis $\ne$ Schauder basis".  A mathematician will use "basis" by itself for his favorite one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The unique decomposition is as an *infinite* combination (series) of the complex characters, while a linear basis is a set of vectors such that any element of the space can be expressed as a *finite* combination.

The set $B$ such that any element of the space $V\supseteq B$ can be uniquely expressed as an infinite combination of elements of $B$ is called Schauder basis, as indicated by Brian M. Scott in the comment, as opposed to linear basis, usually called Hamel basis in functional analytic contexts.

For any cardinal number $\kappa$, there is a Banach space with a Schauder basis of cardinality $\kappa$ -- the Hilbert space of Hilbert dimension $\kappa$, for instance, but none of them have linear dimension $\aleph_0$.